# Does CSS animation cause Angular 2 to stop rendering?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I can see from `console.logs` that the variable is updating every second.  But the {{variable}} in the HTML isn't.  If I select the text it updates, or if the container div is animated the variable updates.

[image: preview]

In the `.ts` I have a

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.ref.detectChanges();
  }
```

and I tried calling `this.ref.detectChanges()` every second when I update the variable.

All of the `{{}}` are not being updated until something else happens. A `*ngIf` displays something, or a CSS animation is triggered. No errors in the console.

CSS animation for the drawer :

```
.moveOutProductDrawer{
    left: -250px;
    animation: scootch 0.3s forwards;
}

@keyframes scootch {
    100% { left: -250px !important; }
}
```

And in another part of the `.ts` I'm changing the `height` and `width` directly.

Has anyone experienced this before? Does the presence of CSS animation mess with Angular?

Comment: Without html or ts code it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, when I change how the window is positioned into the center of the screen, everything is back to normal.

```
.bigFlexcontainer{
    /* display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center; */
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

with position relative and no more flex, the variables are updating correctly and all is well.  Probably shouldn't matter, but in this case it solved the problem.